# If linear transformation $T$ is not invertible, then its pseudo-inverse $T^\dagger$ is not linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ that is not invertible, is it correct to say its pseudo-inverse $T^\dagger$ is not linear? since it's defined by

$$T^\dagger(y):=\lbrace{T_{N(T)^\perp}^{-1}(y), y\in Range(T)\\0, y\in Range(T)^\perp},$$

where $T_{N(T)^\perp}:N(T)^\perp\to Range(T),$ is invertible. And I also noticed that $T^\dagger$ is not one-one and not onto. My proof:

Let $y_1\in R(T),y_2\in R(T)^\perp,y_1,y_2\not=0,$ let $y=y_1+y_2.$ Suppose $y\in R(T)^\perp,$ then $T^\dagger(y)=0,$ but $T^\dagger(y_1)+T^\dagger(y_2)=T_{N(T)^\perp}^{-1}(y_1)\not=0,$ since $y_1\not=0.$ So $T^\dagger(y)\not=T^\dagger(y_1)+T^\dagger(y_2).$

If so, is there any consequence of non-linearity of $T^\dagger$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not such.

If $y_1+y_2\in R (T)^\perp $ with $y_1\in R (T) $ and $y_2\in R (T)^\perp $, then $y_1=0$.

Comment: So pseudo-inverse is always linear. Thank you~

Comment: Glad I could help.